# Visual C++ 2008 Linking (specifically embedding manifest) taking too long

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

Normally I would refrain from asking vague questions but in this case I cannot find enough information to even start looking into fixing the issue.

My project is small (to give you an idea: Vector/Matrix math, and some core data structures such as Arrays, Lists and Strings). Some other much bigger projects I tried link really quickly and do not spend too much time embedding the manifest.

I am compiling the debug version of the library. Release version exhibits the same problem.

I would appreciate pointing me in the right direction on where to find information regarding this (I don't even know what the manifest is apart from simple explanations).

Comment: From the build time, anywhere between 25-35 seconds just on the linking. Normally, on very large projects, I have never experienced this. Embedding manifest part of the process takes maybe a second.

Comment: Use ProcMon from MS to find out what it's doing.  You might be able to figure it out from the pattern of file accesses.

Comment: @HansPassant: That was it. I added exceptions to Microsoft Security Essentials scanner (*.manifest and other extensions related to VS and C++) and it fixed the issue. If you put that as the answer, I'll checmark it.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! I had the same issue and @HansPassant really got the point. I did the same thing: I added exceptions on Microsoft Security Essentials for my Project and MS Visual Studio folders and the "embedding the manifest" process of visual studio became so much faster. Thanks so much again!

Comment: The problem for me involved Interprocedural Optimization. See [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/294016) for an extended discussion, but the basic idea is to turn it off for every project in both the compiler and linker options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans Passant mentioned, the problem was caused by the virus scanner. Adding an exception to the folder and file extensions related to the compiler fixes the issue.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!
I added exceptions on Microsoft Security Essentials for my Project and MS Visual Studio folders and the "embedding the manifest" process of visual studio became so much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Exclude the processes "cl.exe", "link.exe" and "mt.exe" from your virus scanner.  That covers most build output.